# Member initialization in constructors

Tags: c++, class-constructors

Can someone please tell, in this code how to declare the constructor such that when the object is instantiated, height is initialized with passed value while width is always default (2 in the case below).

```
class rectangle{
    int width, height;
public:
    //  rectangle(int w = 1, int h = 1): width(w), height(h){}
    rectangle(int w = 2, int h=1): width(w) {height = h;}
    int getW(){return width;}
    int getH(){return height;}
};
int main()
{
    rectangle r1(1);
    rectangle r2(2);
    rectangle r3(4);
    rectangle r4(5);
    cout << "w = " << r1.getW() <<" h = " << r1.getH() << endl;
    cout << "w = " << r2.getW() <<" h = " << r2.getH() << endl;
    cout << "w = " << r3.getW() <<" h = " << r3.getH() << endl;
    cout << "w = " << r4.getW() <<" h = " << r4.getH() << endl;
}
Output with above code:
w = 1 h = 1
w = 2 h = 1
w = 4 h = 1
w = 5 h = 1
```

Can someone tell me how to declare the constructor so that the output is like below (I want to declare the object with only one parameter)?

```
w = 1 h = 1
w = 1 h = 2
w = 1 h = 4
w = 1 h = 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wording in your question is a bit unclear. It sounds like you want to completely ignore the width argument, and just make the width 2, while the height is optional, and defaults to 1. If that is the case, then you can simply do this:

```
rectangle(int, int h=1) :width(2), height(h) {}
```

But my mind reading skills tell me that is not really what you want (mainly because it's a stupid thing to do). I have a hunch that you simply worded your question wrong, and that you actually want something like this:

```
rectangle(int w, int h) :width(w), height(h) {} // handles 2 arguments
rectangle(int h=1) :width(2), height(h) {}      // handles 0 or 1 arguments
```

This configuration allows three call signatures.

- 2 arguments, first goes to width, and the second goes to height.
- 1 argument, which goes to height, and width becomes 2
- 0 arguments, width becomes 2, height becomes 1

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, you are correct, my wording was confusing. I am learning from an online lecture series and really wanted to understand how members are initialized, so this is mostly a theoretical exercise. Broadly speaking, What I wanted to learn is when there are more than 1 arguments, how to initialize the 1st argument (width in this case) with default value. All my constructor combinations seemed to pass the value to width, leaving height at default. Does that make sense?

Comment: @kaushal98: Yeah, that makes sense. It is not possible though, not with just one function. You can, however, simulate it with multiple overloads, which is what my answer demonstrates.

Comment: @Banjamin: sorry accidentally deleted my earlier comment. I guess this is not possible, or even stupid but I'd still like to confirm. Can we define the construct such that when instantiated like rectangle r1(1), r2(2), r1 sets w and r2 sets h?

Comment: @kaushal98: Sure. Just use an `if` statement inside the constructor: `if (parameter == 1) width = 1; if (parameter == 2) height = 2;` -- But what would you want to do in case of the other ~4 billion possible values?

Comment: :) my bad, I meant we can somehow specify that this time I want to pass the value to W, and this time to H, I just used 1, 2 as examples, it could be anything. But, now I know for sure, it's just not possible  to select W or H if there only one argument.

Comment: @kaushal98: Read about the Named Constructor Idiom: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/named-ctor-idiom.html